# Hierarchical SQL query not returning level

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a typical SQL Server hierarchical query:

```
WITH bhp AS (
   SELECT name, 0 AS level
   FROM dbo.BhpNode
   WHERE parent_id IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.name, level + 1
   FROM dbo.BhpNode a
   INNER JOIN dbo.BhpNode b
      ON b.bhp_node_id = a.parent_id )
  SELECT * FROM bhp
```

This seems to match the various examples of hierarchical queries I've found around the web, but for some reason it's producting this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Invalid column name 'level'.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've stared at it too long to see it. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recursive section of the CTE, one of the tables you reference should be the CTE itself, shouldn't it? At the moment you are just self-joining `BhpNode`, and it doesn't have a `level` column itself.

Comment: BINGO! The reference to the CTE in the recursive section wasn't obvious in the examples I was looking at and got lost when translating to my tables. I knew it felt wrong to reference level without defining it, and now I know why. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

Your query isn't recursive - you have to select from `bhp` inside the second part of the recursive CTE. Try this instead:

```
WITH bhp AS (
   SELECT *, 0 AS [level]
   FROM dbo.BhpNode
   WHERE parent_id IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.*, [level] + 1
   FROM bhp a
   INNER JOIN dbo.BhpNode b
   ON a.bhp_node_id = b.parent_id)
SELECT * FROM bhp
```